# How to get the information in the console to a textbox

Tags: vb.net, printing, textbox, console

I'm writing a code using vb.net that can get some information from a radar sensor connected to the computer through a device called CANcaseXL ,, I added the dll file reference corresponding to the CANcaseXL driver and in the manual there is a command that let me print the information that goes to the CANcaseXL to the console (the command is xlPrintRx(XLClass.xl_event receivedEvent)) and its a continuous real-time data going from the radar to the computer through the CANcaseXL.
Now I can see the data in the console but I need to extract it like print it to a textbox maybe then do the calculations but I don't know how.

I will appreciate any help !

this like the main code I have been working on, I got most of it using the XL Driver Library - .NET Wrapper Description >> http://www.labviewforum.de/attachment.php?aid=43764 and a ready made application.

Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading
Imports vxlapi_NET20
Imports System.IO

Public Class Main

## Region "DLL_Import"

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Shared Function WaitForSingleObject(ByVal handle As Integer, ByVal timeOut As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

## End Region

## Region "GLOBALS"

```
Shared CANDemo_TxChannel As xlSingleChannelCAN_Port
Shared CANDemo_RxChannel As xlSingleChannelCAN_Port


Private RxThread As Thread

Private Enum WaitResults : int

    WAIT_ABANDONED = &H80
    WAIT_FAILED = &HFFFFFFF
    WAIT_OBJECT_0 = &H0
    WAIT_TIMEOUT = &H102
    INFINITE = &HFFFF
End Enum
```

## End Region

```
Declare Function AllocConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Int32
Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Int32

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



    AllocConsole() 

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0

    Dim Max As Double
    Dim Min As Double

    Dim id As String
    Dim dlc As String
    Dim data As String

    Max = Val(TextBox1.Text)
    Min = Val(TextBox2.Text)

    id = Val(TextBox3.Text)
    dlc = Val(TextBox4.Text)
    data = TextBox5.Text
    If data = "" Then
        data = 0
    End If

    Dim Max_hex As Double = Val("&H" & Max)
    Dim Min_hex As Double = Val("&H" & Min)

    If (Max < 1 Or Min < 0) Then
        MsgBox("Please fill the range fields!!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        GoTo C
    End If

    CANDemo_TxChannel = New xlSingleChannelCAN_Port("xlCANdemo NET", Convert.ToUInt32(0))
    CANDemo_RxChannel = New xlSingleChannelCAN_Port("xlCANdemo NET", Convert.ToUInt32(0))

    If (CANDemo_TxChannel.xlCheckPort() And CANDemo_RxChannel.xlCheckPort()) Then
        Label10.BackColor = Color.Green
        Label11.Text = "CAN Connected ..."
      ' these two commands print the configuration for the CANcaseXL device
        CANDemo_TxChannel.xlPrintConfig()
        CANDemo_RxChannel.xlPrintConfig()

        CANDemo_RxChannel.xlResetAcceptanceFilter()
        CANDemo_RxChannel.xlCanAddAcceptanceRange(Convert.ToUInt32(Min_hex), Convert.ToUInt32(Max_hex))

        CANDemo_TxChannel.xlActivate()
        CANDemo_RxChannel.xlActivate()

        Dim RxThread As New Thread(AddressOf RX_Thread)
        RxThread.Start()

        If MsgBox("Are you sure you wont to transmit ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Transmission") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then

            CANDemo_TxChannel.xlTransmit(Convert.ToUInt32(id, 16), Convert.ToUInt16(dlc, 16), Convert.ToUInt64(data, 16))
            ProgressBar1.Value = 100
            MsgBox("Data Transmited!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Transmission")

        Else
        End If

    Else
        Label10.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label11.Text = "CAN Disconnected!!"
        MsgBox("Check the device connection!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "CAN disconnected")

        CANDemo_TxChannel.xlClosePort()
        CANDemo_RxChannel.xlClosePort()

    End If
```

C:

```
End Sub
```

## Region "EVENT THREAD (RX)"

```
Public Shared Sub RX_Thread()


    Dim receivedEvent As XLClass.xl_event = New XLClass.xl_event

    Dim xlStatus As XLClass.XLstatus = XLClass.XLstatus.XL_SUCCESS

    Dim waitResult As WaitResults


    While (True)

        waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(CANDemo_RxChannel.eventHandle, 1000)

        If (waitResult <> WaitResults.WAIT_TIMEOUT) Then

            xlStatus = XLClass.XLstatus.XL_SUCCESS

            While (xlStatus <> XLClass.XLstatus.XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY)

                xlStatus = CANDemo_RxChannel.xlReceive(receivedEvent)

                If (xlStatus = XLClass.XLstatus.XL_SUCCESS) Then

                  ' this command let the coming results from the Radar printed to the console
                    CANDemo_RxChannel.xlPrintRx(receivedEvent)
                End If
            End While
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

## End Region

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far.  With a rare API like that, no-one's going to know how to work with it off the top of their head.

Comment: You can get the stream with Console.OpenStandardOutput/Console.Out but they might offer a way to set the stream in their API.

Comment: I added the code ,, 
the_lotus can you show me an easy example of using Console.OpenStandardOutput/Console.Out please ?

Comment: I tried   ,, Dim writer As StreamWriter = Nothing
              writer = New StreamWriter("output.txt")
               Console.SetOut(writer) ,, and I got the result in the txt file but I need them into a textbox show-up while the program is running

Comment: I found the solution on the internet >> http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_3599261_2/Redirect-IO-to-a-TextBoxWriter-in-NET.htm
 ,,, but thanks for the help guys :)